# Axis2 hide operation from web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, complextype

how can I un-expose an operation from a service, Java class, without making it private?

```
public class Service {
      public Banana[] getBananas(){}
      public Apple[] getApples(){}          
      public Basket getBasket(){}

      // workaround, which I don't need as operation
      public BasketFunction exposeBasketFunctionType()
}

public class Basket {
      private int size;
      private BasketFunction function;

      // getters and setters section
}

public class BasketFunction {
     private String position;
     public void swingTops();

      // getters and setters section
}
```

problem is in this case that the `complexTypeMap` from `TypeTable` doesn't "know" who `BasketFunction` is, and this has to be exposed directly in the service so that the `getBasket()` operation can work.

Comment: This question is too short and unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Nicholas - how is it now, clear enough? :)